# Finding the conjugate of a function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-analysis

I know that the Fenchel conjugate of a function is 
$$f^*(x^*) = \sup_x\{\langle x, x^*\rangle - f(x)\}.$$
However, how do I find the Fenchel conjugate of the function
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{p}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p$$ where $1 < p < \infty$.

I have tried differentiating the equation and taking it to be $= 0$ but I cannot seem to reach any answer.

Comment: [This survey of the Legendre Fenchel transform](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ahanda/lfreport.pdf) discusses this example (see example 4). I do not fully trust their computations (they seem to use $\|x\|$ to denote $\|x\|_2$, $\|x\|_p$, and $\|x\|_q$ for $(1/p)+(1/q) = 1$, and "cancel" certain inequivalent norms). Still, it may be a useful resource if you are stuck --- in particular I see no issue with the computation of the maximizer of the supremum being $x = \frac{x^*}{\|x^*\|_p^{\frac{p-2}{p-1}}}$, which sounds like information you do not yet know.

Comment: Trying to be careful tracking the relevant norms throughout, I end up getting to $$f^*(x^*) = \|x^*\|_p^q\left(\frac{\|x^*\|_2^2}{\|x^*\|_p^2} - \frac{1}{p}\right)$$ where $q$ is the Holder conjugate of $p$. Upon identifying $\|\cdot\|_q, \|\cdot\|_p, \|\cdot\|_2$ this recovers $f^*(x^*) = \frac{\|x^*\|^q}{q}$, the result the survey claims (as a sanity check to my computation).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems like I have not learnt this material, just wondering, for the example in the linked pdf, how did they perform the steps (61-62) and (63-64). How did they convert to and fro a norm?

Comment: In 61 -> 62 I believe the expressions should be $z = |y|^{p-2} y$, so an absolute value, not a norm (that distinction won't matter for what I'm about to say, as both absolute values and norms are homogenous). Taking the absolute value of both sides, and using that for any constant $c$ $|cx| = c|x|$, we recover their step. 63 -> 64 simply takes the expression for $|y|$ (line 63) and substitutes it into equation 61.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be, somewhat expectedly, $$f^*(x^*) = \frac{\|x^*\|_q^q}{q}, \quad \frac1q + \frac1p = 1$$ as indicated in the comments to the OP. The paper linked there was already rightfully identified as sketchy, the derivation there is wrong on several levels, which is why I am including this answer.

I will use $q$ for the conjugated exponent to $p$ in the following without mentioning this explicitly. Let $$G(x) := \langle x^*,x \rangle - f(x).$$ First note that $\frac1q \|x^*\|_q^q$ is an upper bound on $G$ since $$\langle x^*,x\rangle \leq \frac{\|x^*\|_q^q}{q} + \frac{\|x\|_p^p}{p}.$$ Thus, if a stationary point $\bar x$ of $G$ realizes this upper bound, we are done.

Now, $$\partial_j G(x) = x^*_j - |x_j|^{p-2}x_j,$$ hence $\nabla G(x) = 0$ if and only if $x^*_j = |x_j|^{p-2}x_j$ for each $j$. (The linked paper gets this wrong and then proceeds to mix up all norms.) It is easy to see that $\alpha(t) = |t|^{p-2}t$ and $\omega(s) := |s|^{q-2}s$ are bijective functions on $\mathbb{R}$ which are inverse to each other. Hence $x^*_j = |x_j|^{p-2}x_j$ if and only if $x_j = |x^*_j|^{q-2}x_j^*$. So this is the designated maximizer which we call $\bar x$. There holds $\|\bar x\|_p^{q-1} = \|x^*\|_q$ and thus indeed
$$G(\bar x) = \|x^*\|_q^q - \frac1p \|x^*\|_q^q = \frac{\|x^*\|_q^q}q.$$

Comment: To clarify, is the above answer correct for my question? Since the linked paper is solving for f(x) = norm(x)^p, whereas my question is solving for f(x) = abs(x)^p or are they the same?

Comment: @JustAPerson the $f$ you give in the question is $f(x) = \frac1p \|x\|_p^p$.